How to get the current users window login for audit table
I have a table which needs to be audited for add, update, and delete actions. The SQL I have written successfully adds rows to the audit table when each of these events take place. The problem is that the column 'ActionedBy' is populated with the databases security username 'Database_User' instead of the users AD Login.
I currently use :
INSERT INTO Audit(CallID, Action, ActionedBy, ActionDate)
SELECT CallID, 'INSERT', SUSER_NAME(), GETDATE()
FROM INSERTED;


SUSER_NAME returns the (server) LOGIN name, not the (database) USER name. If you have the database USER name, you aren't inserting SUSER_NAME in your code.

Or, perhaps, are you using a contained database? Then the USER won't have a LOGIN.

Or, another perhaps, you are using SQL Authentication? If so, SQL Server will have no idea what the AD credentials are of the person who connected is.

Ah I see so because I am using SQL Authentication it's going to use the security username. I understand now. Thank you.
